# make text appear when hovering on a specific list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The challenge I face is making it so that hovering over the Chevrons to reveal a text box that contains additional information. I have done extensive searching online however every attempt I have made hasn't done the trick.

```
$('#breadcrumb li a').hover(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('href').slice(1)
    $('.info div').removeClass('active');
    $('.info .' + a).addClass('active')
})

$('#breadcrumb li a').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.info div').removeClass('active');
})
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9aet4kfj/

Comment: As a side-note: javascript is not required for this.  This can be accomplished purely with CSS and some adjacent sibling selectors, assuming you have the ability to modify the markup a bit...

Comment: You can use the 'title' attribute on the <li> which will produce a tooltip on hover. Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a variety of problems going on.

Here's a runnable [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/03c54aes/) that works.

1. You did not have jQuery loaded.  NOTE: Even after loading jQuery, WHERE you put this script matters, as you don't have it in a `document.ready` function, it's still likely to fail.
2. You had a few errors in your CSS.  For example, `display: relative` is not valid - I've modified to `display: block`
3. I've refactored the javascript to be more semantically correct.  Using the href and class tags is a "hack", it's better to use `data-` tags.

The modified script looks like so:

```
// no-conflict safe document-ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // switched to 'mouseover', using 'on' (from 'hover')
  $('#breadcrumb li a').on('mouseover', function() {
    // switched to using data attributes instead of href
    var id = $(this).data('toggle-id');
    $('.info div').removeClass('active');
    // switched to using data attributes instead of class
    $('.info [data-content-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('active')
  });

  $('#breadcrumb li a').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.info div').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

For the modified HTML and CSS, see the jsFiddle above.

Additionally - per my comment above - this could absolutely be done with pure CSS, if you are able to modify the layout / markup at all.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. I knew it was possible in pure CSS however I was pretty sure it involved using psuedo elements, both of which I am already employing to provide the chevron shape.

Comment: Actually the CSS solution doesn't require pseudo elements at all :)